# How can I do a clean install?

Tags: 12.04, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A fresh install and clean up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283/a-fresh-install-and-clean-up)

My upgrade to 12.04 seems to be slow and there seems to be something that is sapping my system resources.

I have no data on the machine - everything is in the cloud including Xmarks bookmarks for Firefox.

Is it best to do a clean installation? If so, how do I do it?

Thanks
John.

Comment: This one is stil valid: [A fresh install and clean up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1283/a-fresh-install-and-clean-up) Follow the accepted answer and skip anything you do not need (my guess: start at the 2nd 4th pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Put the instillation disc  in your computer, you can get an image from [http/www.ubuntu.com/download](http://ubuntu.com/download) when the disc loads select install, the select erase disk and install Ubuntu and you will be guided though the rest

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I would add that if you are on a dual boot system with Windows, check that you are not using a wubi installation and that you are booting from the disk and not running it from Windows.