# Can I "upgrade" to the same version of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

Each time I put a bootable drive in the usb slot, it asks me if I want to install it. Can I use it to reinstall my OS without formatting my harddrive?

Comment: What do you want to do? Simply reinstall Ubuntu without losing your home directory?

Comment: Well, I backed everything up, but it's been running out of battery really quickly lately, and so I'd like to reinstall the OS to clean it up.

Comment: I don't think this is 100% OS related. A battery gets more weak the longer you use it. Reinstalling the OS might not solve your problem. Did you try whether it behaves the same when running a Live system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please correct me if I'm wrong - I haven't used Ubuntu in a while since I moved to Arch Linux.*

I believe Ubiquity (the installer used in the Ubuntu LiveUSB) has the ability to reinstall Ubuntu over a previous install of Ubuntu while retaining all personal documents, pictures, music, etc. - in a nutshell, your home folder.

On the "Installation Type" screen during the install process from an Ubuntu LiveUSB, it should show an option along the lines of `Replace Ubuntu <version> with Ubuntu <version>`. These can be the same versions, and should preserve the contents of your home folder.

**Note: This will not save your installed programs.** If you're looking to do that, check out [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1283/a-fresh-install-and-clean-up?rq=1).

Comment: Can I use Ubiquity to install Xubuntu or another version of ubuntu?

Comment: Yes. All officially supported distributions of Ubuntu (Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, UbuntuGnome, Edubuntu, etc.) use Ubiquity and support this feature, as far as I know.

Comment: Huh, for whatever reason, it was not detecting that I had an upgrade in the usb slot, and I couldn't figure out how to upgrade via Ubiquity since the option wasn't coming up. I wound up backing up my home drive and wiping anyway.